# Cytoscape graph gets shifted while re-drawing on another div

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

I have set of divs where in each div has a cytoscape diagram. Whenever a div is clicked, I am trying to draw same cytoscape graph on another bigger div. Am able to get nodes/edges of a respective graph on click of a div.

```
var cy = $('#'+id).cytoscape('get');
var eleData = cy.elements().jsons();
```

Drawing the graph on bigger div using above data by :

```
$("#biggerView").cytoscape({
    //Style properties are set
    elements : eleData,
    ready : function() {
        window.cynew = this;
        cynew.elements().unselectify();
    }
});
```

Am able to get graph on new div, but the problem is both the graphs(small and big graphs) gets shifted from original position.
Tried using `cy.fit()`, `cy.resize()` but it did not help.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or at least a screenshot of what you exactly mean by "_gets shifted_"?

Comment: I wanted to redraw the same graph on a bigger div. Wanted to reuse the same json elements(nodes and edges supplied to earlier graph) with the help of following lines:

var cy = $('#'+id).cytoscape('get');
var eleData = cy.elements().jsons();

But as you can see in the above image, black border is my div where i wanted to draw my graph(have specified width and height), but instead canvas is drawing graph in blue border div.(Graph is getting shifted).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

If you just want to copy how things look, you may just want to use `cy.png()` and `<img>` tags.  That would probably be more scalable and would guarantee that relative sizing is maintained.

If you want interactive, secondary graphs -- then you'll need to calculate the zoom/pan diff from the primary graph to each secondary graph to maintain a relative scale.

Comment: I wanted to redraw the same graph on a bigger div.Wanted to reuse the same json elements(nodes and edges supplied to earlier graph) with the help of following lines: var cy = $('#'+id).cytoscape('get'); var eleData = cy.elements().jsons(); But as you can see in the above image, black border is my div where i wanted to draw my graph(have specified width and height), but instead canvas is drawing graph in blue border div.(Graph is getting shifted)